# How should i implement this Tree Like concept in Java?

Tags: java, tree, hashmap

Please have a look:

[image: Tree Like architecture]

So basically I have a tree like architecture which is not really a tree because the root node might or might not be available at all times.

Root is connected to many children which in turn may or may not be connected to other childs. All nodes at one particular level or similar objects with different id's as their identifiers.

I am thinking to implement it as a tree but then with a large data set it may be hard to search particular node. Or should i may be make a single Map Object at each level and based upon their key i will be able to serach their relation to parent node if it exists or not??

Or do you think there is anyother better way of doing this, because if i take it as a tree it would grow randomly, plus in it's extension i have a problem that some children will have many parent nodes and this is probably not possible in tree??

Please suggest some implementation idea?

Comment: What does the tree actually represent?  Can you provide a concrete example of how you would search it and what you would expect to obtain?  Essentially every OO application is a tree (or graph) at some level so without some more concrete detail about the problem domain it's difficult to answer this.

Comment: If a child can have multiple parents it is definitely not a tree.

Comment: @Adamski, actually each node is an Object. Actually i am confused about how to make relationship between then based upon their connections. It is just like you have many objects which are randomly connected to each other (but very similar to tree like structure), and i need to make up some structure through which i can know their relationship to each other. It is like we have vertices and edges are defining their connection. So i am looking for some idea about how to define these edges so that i can keep track of their child and parent structure... I hope you got it what i am askking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could represent it as an oriented graph: each node has incoming edges from its parents and outgoing edges to its children:

```
public class Node {
    private List<Object> parents;   // incoming
    private List<Object> children;   // outgoing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a look at the [b-tree concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)